# how to get contacts created by currently logged in user in grails

Tags: grails

I have implemented spring security service for user authentication in my grails application.
I have Subscriber.groovy(user table) and Contact.groovy domains. Once a subscriber(user) logs in, he/she can create contacts.There is hasMany relationship between Subscriber and Contact domain.

*Problem*: I have implemented search functionality for contacts created by currently logged user or subscriber on contact page. It works fine but it fetch all contacts in system but I want only contacts those are created by currently logged in subscriber(user).
How to search contacts those are created by currently logged in subscriber.

*Method for searching contacts from contact table*

```
def searchAJAX = {
    def contacts = Contact.findAllByNameLike("%${params.query}%")
      //Create XML response
      render(contentType: "text/xml") {
        results() {
          contacts.each { contact ->
           result(){
             name(contact.name)
              //Optional id which will be available in onItemSelect
                id(contact.id)
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

}

*ContactController.groovy*

```
package com.vproc.member

import grails.converters.*

class ContactController {

  def springSecurityService
    def subscriberService
  def imageUploadService
  def searchableService
  def autoCompleteService

  static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

  def index() {
    redirect(action: "list", params: params)
  }

  def list() {

    Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = Subscriber.get( springSecurityService.principal.id )
    List<Contact>contactsList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    loggedinSubscriber?.contacts.each { it ->
        contactsList.add(it)
    }
    [contactInstanceList:contactsList , contactInstanceTotal: contactsList.size() ]
  }

  def create() {
    [contactInstance: new Contact(params)]
  }

  def save() {
    // params.birthday = Date.parse( 'MM/dd/yyyy', params.birthday )
    if (params.birthday){
        params.birthday = (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")).parse(params.birthday)
    }
    def contactInstance = new Contact(params)
    Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = Subscriber.get( springSecurityService.principal.id )
    if (loggedinSubscriber == null)
      System.out.println("not able to save")

    else {
      if (!loggedinSubscriber.contacts){
        loggedinSubscriber.contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
      }
      loggedinSubscriber.contacts.add(contactInstance)

      if (!loggedinSubscriber.save(flush: true)) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'contact.label', default: 'Contact'), contactInstance.id])
        render(view: "create", model: [contactInstance: contactInstance])
        return
      }
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'contact.label', default: 'Contact'), contactInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "list")
  }



  // enable search for contacts
  def contact_search = {
    def query = params.q
    if(query){
      def srchResults = searchableService.search(query)
      render(view: "list",
        model: [contactInstanceList: srchResults.results,
        contactInstanceTotal:srchResults.total])
    }
    else{
        render "not record found";
    }
  }

  // fetch name from contact table for autocomplete on contact
  def searchAJAX = {

    def contacts = Contact.findAllByNameLike("%${params.query}%")
      //Create XML response
      render(contentType: "text/xml") {
        results() {
          contacts.each { contact ->
           result(){
             name(contact.name)
              //Optional id which will be available in onItemSelect
                id(contact.id)
            }
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

*Contact.groovy*

```
package com.vproc.member

import java.util.Date;

import com.vproc.common.Tag;
import com.vproc.enquiry.ContactType;
import grails.converters.JSON;

class Contact {

    String name
    String phoneNumber
    String emailAddress
    Gender gender
    String url
    String note
    byte[] image
    String address
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    ContactType contactType
    Date birthday

    static belongsTo = [Subscriber]
    static hasMany = [tags:Tag ,   shares: SharedContact]
    static  constraints = {
        image nullable: true
        phoneNumber nullable: true
        url nullable :true
        address nullable :true
        gender nullable :true
        note nullable :true
        contactType nullable :true
        birthday nullable :true

    }

    static mapping = {
     note(type: 'text')
  }



     //static searchable = [only: ['name', 'emailAddress']]
      static searchable = true

     static scaffold = true
    //static searchable = true
}
```

*Subscriber.groovy*

```
package com.vproc.member

import java.util.Date;

import com.vproc.common.StatusEnum;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Discussion;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Enquiry;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Membership;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Notification;
import com.vproc.enquiry.SharedEnquiry;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Team;
import com.vproc.order.Seat;

class Subscriber extends PartyRole{

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired
    StatusEnum status
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    List<Contact> contacts ;

    static belongsTo = [ customer: Customer]
    static hasMany = [seats: Seat, ownedEnquiries: Enquiry,enquiresSharedWith: SharedEnquiry, enquiriesSharedBy: SharedEnquiry ,
         managedTeams: Team , memberships: Membership, contacts: Contact , sharedByContacts: SharedContact, sharedWithContacts: SharedContact,
          vContacts: VContact, partOf: VContact,  sharedbyVContacts: SharedVcontact, sharedWithVcontacts: SharedVcontact,
          notifications: Notification, discussions: Discussion]
    static mappedBy = [ managedTeams : "manager" , enquiresSharedWith: "sharedWith" , enquiriesSharedBy: "sharedBy"  ,
                                                   sharedByContacts : "sharedBy" , sharedWithContacts : "sharedWith" ,
                                                   vContacts: "forSubscriber"  ,  partOf :"ofContact",
                                                   sharedbyVContacts: "sharedby" , sharedWithVcontacts :"sharedWith"
                                                    ]


    static constraints = {
        username  validator : { val , obj ->
                                 if (obj.status != StatusEnum.Pending)
                                        val!= null
                               }
        username unique: true
        password validator : { val , obj ->
                                    if (obj.status != StatusEnum.Pending)
                                        val != null
                             }

        contacts nullable: true
        notifications nullable : true
        username nullable: true
        password nullable: true

    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        SubscriberRole.findAllBySubscriber(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

*save action for Contact controller*

```
def save() {
    // params.birthday = Date.parse( 'MM/dd/yyyy', params.birthday )
    if (params.birthday){
        params.birthday = (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")).parse(params.birthday)
    }
    def contactInstance = new Contact(params)
    Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = Subscriber.get( springSecurityService.principal.id )
    if (loggedinSubscriber == null)
      System.out.println("not able to save")

    else {
      if (!loggedinSubscriber.contacts){
        loggedinSubscriber.contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
      }
      loggedinSubscriber.contacts.add(contactInstance)

      if (!loggedinSubscriber.save(flush: true)) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'contact.label', default: 'Contact'), contactInstance.id])
        render(view: "create", model: [contactInstance: contactInstance])
        return
      }
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'contact.label', default: 'Contact'), contactInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "list")
  }
```

*Note*: while saving contacts,I have logged in subscriber in save action of Contact controller but I do not know how to use it below method which is searchAjax for searching contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Subscriber` has an association to `Contact` as,

```
class Subscriber {

   static hasMany = [contacts: Contact]

}
```

then, to get all contacts for a subscriber user,

```
subscriberInstance.contacts
```

and to query among contacts of the same subscriber use,

```
subscriberInstance.findByContact('your_query_string')
```

For reference look up querying associations on the documentation http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying

Comment: hi @aldrin, thanks for your reply. I can get all contacts for currently logged in subscriber by loggedinSubscriber.get.contacts(please see in save action of contact controller). But I dnt know how to use it in def contacts = Contact.findAllByNameLike("%${params.query}%"). any idea.

Comment: I have updated question with save method of contact controller. Please check it.

Comment: Does Contact.findAllBySubscriberAndNameLike(loggedInSubscriber, "%${params.query}%") work for you?

Comment: what error did it give? also in Contact, it should be static belongsTo = [subscriber: Subscriber]

Comment: there is no error but it does not show search result. I think you are right here I missed this relationship between Subscriber and contact.